# Export GridView to Excel in GENERAL Format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

I am trying to export my `GridView` to `Excel`. Problem is when I am Exporting it the Default format i set to `Text` but I want it in `General`.
Here is how I am exporting Excel:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Charset = ""
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RawTransactionReport.xls")
'set the response mime type for excel 
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
'create a string writer 
Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter
'create an htmltextwriter which uses the stringwriter 
Dim htmlWrite As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
'tell the datagrid to render itself to our htmltextwriter 
 grdTransactions.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
 'shows number in string format
Dim Style As String = "<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"
'all that's left is to output the html 
Response.Write(Style)
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString)
Response.End()
```

Is there any way I can set it to General? Actually I have number fields that would be `summed`, but if the format is text you cant sum them. So I want it in General format

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't export the data directly from your `GridView`, but would go back to the data source for your GridView and export that instead.

By doing that, you can use one of many free tools out there to create a *real* Excel file.

Here's my free offering (available in VB.Net & C# flavours):

[Export to Excel](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

So, if your GridView was populated with data from a `DataSet` called NukesData , you'd just have to call this:

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(NukesData, "NukesExcel.xlsx", Response)
```